# Regex help, one char, one number and options spl char

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex with below conditions
1) Need at least one character.
2) Need at least one numeric.
3) Character case doesn't matter.
4) Special chars are optional, if used then only these are allowed ~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=.
5) length between 6 to 20.

Sample incomplete jsfidle:

```
1
http://jsfiddle.net/TH2dG/
2
http://jsfiddle.net/mqS3g/
```

Any help would be appreciated...Thanks.

Comment: Rather than jsfiddle links you need to post your attempts in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[~`!@#$%^&*()_+=.a-z0-9-]{6,20}$/i
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cH6qK3/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Anubhava. I was pretty close in my second jsfiddle link but messed up in syntax. Anyways it's working perfect with your help.